# Kendo Grid nested to Multilevel getting error Invalid Template

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to add nested grid upto level 2 with kendo but getting Invalid Template error on bottom most grid.
Here is my code:

```
<script id="ScriptID" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
   @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ViewModel>()
              .Name("gridName")
              .DataSource(dt => dt
                .Ajax()
                .Read(read => read.Action("ActioName", "Controller"))
                )
              .ToClientTemplate()

        )
</script>
```

Comment: try to remove the semicolon when you call the template #= kendo.render(.......).html()), xxx); #

Comment: Actually we are calling the template with '.ClientDetailTemplateId()'